# Is there a more elegant way to execute if statement only if a new date is at least one month different from the current one?

Tags: excel, vba

EDIT: I only want to execute the code if the new date is in the future AND the month is different.

I have two dates. I want to execute code only if the new date is in a different month from the old date, but I need to execute two different types of code:

**1. If the new date's month is in the future**

> e.g. if new date is Jan 15, 2021 and old date is Mar 15, 2020, I want
>   to execute part 1.

**2. A different code if the new date's month is in the past**

> e.g. if new date is Mar 15, 2020 and old date is Jan 15, 2021, I want
>   to execute part 2

I think there's a better way to do it than what I've done in the code

```
 Dim old_date as variant
 Dim new_date as variant

**'NOTE: For the intents of this code, the new_date and old_date have been previously defined by the user in a previous part of code**

 If CLng(Format(new_date, "yyyymm")) <> CLng(Format(old_date, "yyyymm")) Then

      If CLng(Format(new_date, "yyyymm")) > CLng(Format(old_date, "yyyymm")) Then
           'Temporary msgbox for my testing purposes
           MsgBox "Your new date is in a month in the future"
           'Additional code to execute
      Else
           'Temporary msgbox for my testing purposes
           MsgBox "Your new date is in a month in the past"
           'Additional code to execute
      End If

 End If
```

My code works as is, but I know there's a better way to do what I did than what I did

Comment: How are you getting the value for `new_date` and `old_date`?

Comment: Assume the new_date and old_date have been previously defined by the user. I will update the code to explain this

Comment: yes but how? It is from a textbox? a range? a date control? Because if you store it as a date then you can do a direct comparision rather then converting it to a format and then converting it usinf Clng etc...

Comment: Ah, good point. The user changes a cell on the sheet which is stored as a date

Comment: Then, if it is a valid date then instead of `If CLng(Format(new_date, "yyyymm")) > CLng(Format(old_date, "yyyymm")) Then` you can say `If new_date > old_date Then` and so on...

Comment: Ah yes, I had originally thought of if new_date>old_date but I only want to execute part 1 of the code if new_date>old_date and the month is different (e.g. If new_date>old_date & month(new_date)<>month(old_date))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DateDiff` with a first argument of "m" will return a number equal to the difference in months. if it is positive its forward, negative is back, 0 is same.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/datediff-function

```
Dim old_date as date
Dim new_date as date
dim monthdatediff as long

monthdatediff = datediff("m", old_date, new_date)

if monthdatediff = 0 then
    msgbox "Same Month"
elseif monthdatediff > 0 then
    msgbox "Future Month"
else
    msgbox "Past Month"
end if
```

Comment: Does this work if the new date is Jan 1, 2020 but the old date is Dec 12, 2019?

The month value of the new date is 1
The month value of the old date would be 12

Comment: Yes, it will return a 1. If it was Jan 1, 2020 and Dec 12, 2018 it would return 13

Comment: Ah gotcha. I was struggling with how to word my original question. Basically I need to only execute the 1st part of the code if it meets two conditions: 
1) new date is in the future
2) the new date's month is different from the old date's month

I need to execute code part 2 if it meets the conditions that:
1) the new date entered is before the old date
2) the new date's month is different from the old date's month

Comment: @newtovba `datediff("m", DateSerial(2019, 12, 12), DateSerial(2020, 1, 1))` == 1, fyi (not 13)

Comment: I said 2018 not 2019

Comment: @Warcupine - Just marked this as the correct answer! This is what I was looking for - thanks for providing the link for the datedif - I should have looked into the Microsoft doc for how it calculates the difference

Answer (score 1):

> Ah yes, I had originally thought of if new_date>old_date but I only want to execute part 1 of the code if new_date>old_date and the month is different (e.g. If new_date>old_date & month(new_date)<>month(old_date)) – newtovba 3 mins ago

In that case, find the month and work with that as shown below.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim old_date As Date
    Dim new_date As Date
    Dim oldDateMonth As Long
    Dim newDateMonth As Long

    '~~> Populating from B2 and B3. Change as applicable
    old_date = [b2]: new_date = [b3]

    '~~> Get the month
    oldDateMonth = Month(old_date)
    newDateMonth = Month(new_date)

    If new_date > old_date Then
        If oldDateMonth <> newDateMonth Then

        '
        ' Do what you want (PART 1)
        '

        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Ah yes this would be on the path to getting the right answer since I would need to add the else part to execute the code if new_date<old_date & olddatemonth<>newdatemonth

Comment: Then simply add the else if :)

Comment: Yup :) thanks! I've marked it as a +1 (might not show up until I have 15 reputation points)

Comment: Not sure of terminology - I "upvoted" it mainly so that other people who might see this question later can see an alternate solution. In any case, thank you!

Comment: The thought counts :) BTW you will not be able to upvote till you reach (25 points I guess)

Answer (score 0):

Your code look OK. I prefer using the right type (`Date` here): faster and safer.
You could also slightly simplify the logic.

```
 Dim old_date as Date
 Dim new_date as Date


 If new_date > old_date Then
           debug.print now, "Your new date is in a month in the future"
           'Additional code to execute
 ElseIf new_date < old_date
           debug.print "Your new date is in a month in the past"
           'Additional code to execute
 End If
```

Comment: Ah yes, I had originally thought of if new_date>old_date but I only want to execute part 1 of the code if new_date>old_date AND the month is different (e.g. If new_date>old_date & month(new_date)<>month(old_date)). That's my fault for not clarifying the question